# How can I set the notification timestamp for a future date?

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

The default iOS Calendar app sets a notification trigger and its timestamp appear in the UI as "in x min".

Please refer to the screenshot below.

**Is that a private API Apple uses or an open one?**

[image: first screenshot of timestamp with future date]

[image: second screenshot of timestamp with future date]

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is **not publicly available**.

All remote and local notifications created by a third-party application have a timestamp that shows the date when the notification was being displayed for the first time. This means that it's not possible to have a future date for the timestamp.